# How to add number of lines limit to a text file in python

Tags: python, text-files, limit

I am currently doing a python project as part of my syllabus. One of the criteria is that there should be a maximum of 20 players. How can I set this limit? I know how to set them to normal variables inside python but not in an external text file. Could this be done by limiting the number of times the user can input a player? I have added comments so that you know what each statement is doing. And where to add in the code if needed.

```
def playerMenu():
    runningplayer = True
    while runningplayer == True:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print("\n====================================================")
        print("************|Welcome to The Player Menu|************")
        print("====================================================")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        choice = input('''
====================================================

    A: Add Player & Score
    B: Delete Player
    C: View Scores
    D: Back To Main Menu
    E: Exit Menu

====================================================
\nPlease select what you wish to do: ''')

# This ELIF statement will allow the user to write the name and score of the player.
        if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
            save_name = input('Enter your name: ').title()
            save_score = input('Enter your score: ')
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
            text_file.write("\n" + save_name + ' | ' + save_score + "\n")
            text_file.close()
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
            whole_thing = text_file.read()
            print (whole_thing)
            text_file.close()
            
# This ELIF statement will allow the user to delete a player and their score from the text file.
        elif choice == "B" or choice == "b":
            print("These are the current players and their score:")
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
            whole_thing = text_file.read()
            print(whole_thing)
            text_file.close()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            save_delete = input("Please enter the name of the player you wish to delete: ") + " | "
            #print(f"save_delete = {save_delete}")
            with open("highscores.txt", "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                #print(lines)
            with open("highscores.txt", "w") as f:
                for line in lines:
                    if not(line.startswith(save_delete)):
                        f.write(line)

# This ELIF statement will allow the user to view the scores of all players.
        elif choice == "C" or choice == "c":
            with open('highscores.txt', encoding = 'utf-8', mode = 'r') as my_file:
                file = open("highscores.txt", encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
                text = file.read()
                print(text)
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish this from a code perspective. You should reference your question prompt, but I expect you are supposed to keep the top 20 scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, before you add the player, you can read the lines from the file. If the number of lines is 20, do not add the player but if it's less you can add them.

A simple way to do this is to use `readlines()` this will return a list with each line. Then you can check the length of the list.

```
# This ELIF statement will allow the user to write the name and score of the player.
save_name = input('Enter your name: ')
save_score = input('Enter your score: ')
text_file = open("untitled.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()
if len(whole_thing) < 20:
    text_file = open("untitled.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("\n" + save_name + ' | ' + save_score + "\n")
    text_file.close()
text_file = open("untitled.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.readlines()
print (whole_thing)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi Prince, thank you for this answer it is really helpful. Just a quick question, do you recommend swapping your chunk of code for the one I have for inputting the names and score?

Comment: @HamzaKhan Sure, that should still work. I only modified it so that I could solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

There're multiple ways to solve this, however, I guess you're expected to treat the high score table as a queue with a fixed maximum length. Each time a new high score is entered, you count all the existing high score entries - if the count exceeds 20, delete the last (oldest) entry.

edit: if you're supposed to save the top 20 scores, you could sort them each time a new one is added and then delete the last (smallest) score.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not making it clear but once there are 20 players, it should notify the user that the maximum amount has been reached and then loop back to the beginning of the menu.

Comment: No problem :) Still, counting the number of existing score entries (after loading the file) sounds best. The limit of 20 coild be hard-coded as a variable, read from some configuration file or given as program input.

Comment: Sounds great! Is it possible for you to make some code as an example of what that would look like? I'm not sure where I'd implement that and what to write. Thank you

Comment: To simplify things, you could format your highscores.txt file to start each score entry with a "#" character. Then, as suggested in Prince's answer, use the readlines method on a file handle: `lines = file.readlines()`. This will return a list containing each line as a separate string. You could iterate over that list and check how many lines start with your special character - that will be your score entry count.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for being so patient! Have a great day